# Can two users have same public IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I want to detect unique user for my site. For this purpose I plan to use user's

**1. Public IP** and **2.Cookie**

But user can clear cookie(or even may not have enabled cookie). Then IP address will be used. But I have heard that public IP can be same for Two PC, even which are not in same Wi-Fi network. **Is it right**?

Comment: Every user connecting to the internet from the same LAN has the same public IP address... A LAN can have more than one wireless network ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I believe that your comment is true only if the LAN is connected to the Internet through a NAT.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Scott Correct. I should have said **may have the same publicIP address** - the point being you cannot rely on public IP to uniquely ID a user.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that sometimes multiple people share a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP which owns the public IP address may assign the address by DHCP, and it may end up being assigned to a different user later. Also, ISPs are now using more CGN which can assign the same public IP address to tens of thousands of users behind the ISP's NAT, and this is becoming more common since ARIN has no more IP address blocks to assign to the ISPs..